# Creating google analytics dashboard

Tags: web-deployment, google-analytics-api

I'm creating web site on zend framework and want to place statistic into my admin panel. Is there any js plugin (something like GA api) for getting styled graphs?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at this:

http://d3js.org/

and that:

http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries/

it depends on what you want to display a line graph, a map ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  *(Disclosure - I work with them)*  EmbeddedAnalytics is based on the GA API.  To do what you are asking is simple:

1. Create Account and grant embeddedanalytics access to your GA data.
2. Define your charts/reports.
3. Get embedding *iframe* code.
4. Embed this code into your site where you want them to show.

Additionally, we are working on creating pre-defined dashboard pages which will allow end-user to embed entire dashboards into a page.